# Problems to keep a three-rows layout after drag and drop

Tags: jquery, layout, drag-and-drop, grid

I wanted to create a row made by some `li` elements inside an `ul`, so I used jquery 1.9.1 and jquery ui. Everything worked properly, however there was something went differently from what I expected. Infact when you try to do drag "Container 4" and drop it in place of "Container 3" the grid changes, getting composed by four rows.

I would like to keep the grid in the original three rows layout.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/ussy1649/j2K86/

Comment: it seems like correct behavior to me. Container #4 is 2x the width of the other containers (including container #3). When you drag container #4 on top of container #3 (i.e. swap places), there isn't enough space to hold container #4, so it simply flows to the next row and the former #3 slot remains empty. Again, the logic seems good.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the logic it's perfect and I know that. But I hoped to use any trick to keep the 3 rows layout. For example not allowing "Container 4" to be in place of "Container 3" position or "Container "5" position, you know.. just not to create a new row..

Answer (score 0):

One option is to tell sortable to ignore the li with id = "special", by adding this line:

```
items: 'li[id!=special]'
```

It's not perfect since it would prevent same-row sorting with #4, but it would partially fix the bigger issue. Your code will look like this:

```
$(function () {

    $("#sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "placeholder",
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: true,
        cursor: 'move',
        items: 'li[id!=special]'
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j2K86/3/